# How to load `application.properties` in vanilla java project without springboot using .jar packaging

Tags: java

I have a java application using the `application.properties` however once it is packaged to `jar` file I am no longer able to access values in the *application.properties* file. How can I load that file on mainly on run time so that i should be able to chenge values and restart the app the use new values.

The application.properties is in the same directory as the java file. Below is the function that is accessing `application.properties`

```
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

        while (true)classLoader();
    }

    private static void classLoader() throws Exception {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try (InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
            properties.load(resourceStream);
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            long rebootTime = 0;
            String restartTime = properties.getProperty("restart.time");
            String restartTime2 = properties.getProperty("restart.time2");
            String restartLocalDateTime = now.toLocalDate() +"T"+ restartTime;
            String restartLocalDateTime2 = now.toLocalDate() +"T"+ restartTime2;
            DateTimeFormatter isoLocalDate = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
            LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(restartLocalDateTime, isoLocalDate);
            LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.parse(restartLocalDateTime2, isoLocalDate);
            if(now.isAfter(dateTime)){
                Duration duration = Duration.between(now, dateTime2.plusMinutes(1440));
                rebootTime = duration.toMillis();
            }else if(now.isAfter(dateTime2)){
                Duration duration = Duration.between(now, dateTime.plusMinutes(1440));
                rebootTime = duration.toMillis();
            }else if(now.isBefore(dateTime)){
                Duration duration = Duration.between(now, dateTime.plusMinutes(1440));
                rebootTime = duration.toMillis();
            }else if(now.isBefore(dateTime2)){
                Duration duration = Duration.between(now, dateTime2.plusMinutes(1440));
                rebootTime = duration.toMillis();
            }

            long sleepingMills = Long.parseLong(properties.getProperty("sleeping.time.millis"));
            List<String> servicesList = List.of(properties.getProperty("services").split(","));
            AbaBundledService abaBundledService = new AbaBundledService();
            abaBundledService.doTheProcess(servicesList,sleepingMills);
            abaBundledService.verifyTheProcess(servicesList,sleepingMills);
            System.out.println("sleeping for "+ rebootTime + " millis");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(rebootTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working for me.

Comment: Why? (must fill space to submit the comment)

Comment: Needs more details. Where did you put the file in the project? Did the property file actually get placed in the JAR? What code are you using to read the file? Please [edit] your question to include these details

Comment: There's nothing really specific about this question vs "reading a file on the classpath", but if you are looking for config files, then [`typesafe config`](https://github.com/lightbend/config) is far more flexible than properties

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the Java Properties API.

```
FileReader reader=new FileReader("application.properties");  
Properties p=new Properties();  
p.load(reader);
```

This might come handy

Comment: So if I package the java to .jar will the *db.properties* be included?

Comment: @Lewis If the file is in `src/main/resources` and you use Maven/Gradle default JAR packaging, it should be